# Android Text To Speech And Numbers

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using Android Text to Speech engine for reading some text and it's working. But my text contains numbers and I want the numbers to be read digit by digit.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but I am still hoping someone knows how I can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API does not allow you to specify how the text should be read so your code has to modify the text input so that it reads the individual numbers.

I suggest adding a space in between each number. That should cause the `TextToSpeech` to read the individual numbers.

If you need some code to help you detect numbers use this:

```
private boolean isNumber(String word)
{
    boolean isNumber = false;
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(word);
        isNumber = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        isNumber = false;
    }
    return isNumber;
}
```

Comment: Yess, spaces :) Thank you... It is very simple but true, i will try.

Comment: Warning: Since Android 4.4, if you submit "1 2 3 4 5" to text-to-speech engine, nothing happens! MUTE! Workaround: Use underlines: "1_2_3_4_5"...

Comment: Does anyone know if the issue with 4.4 pointed out by almisoft was or will be fixed. I also implemented the "underscore workaround". Though, one user reported that the underscores were actually spoken under 4.4.2 : "one underscore two underscore ..." which is obviously not what I want :-)

Comment: I have confirmed that with Android 5.0 and Google TTS Engine 3.8.14, if you use "_", the underscore is spoken. 
But, inserting spaces or "-" worked pretty well.

Comment: And what about Roman numerals? E.g. I have in my text : king Charles IV. and the IV is read as letters, not as number 4. Is for this any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has a minor flaw . If the number has '0' as one of it's digits , it would be read as alphabet 'o' instead of Zero . I would suggest the following solution .

```
 String number = "1230";

 for(int i = 0 ; i < number.size(); i++) {

  /* refer Speech API , Don't use QUEUE_FLUSH as it results in flushing      
     some characters in this case */

   engine.speak(Character.toString(number.charAt(i)),QUEUE_ADD,null);

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/* refer Speech API , Don't use QUEUE_FLUSH as it results in flushing      
some characters in this case */
for(int i = 0 ; i < number.size(); i++) {
  engine.speak(Character.toString(number.charAt(i)),QUEUE_ADD,null); 
}
```